# Facebook API on Windows Phone

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8

I'm struggling to post a picture from my Windows Phone 8 App using the Facebook API.

I start the process with the following

```
Browser.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

var authUrl = facebookClient.GetLoginUrl(new
    {
        client_id = Constants.Facebook.AppId,
        client_secret = Constants.Facebook.AppSecret,
        scope = "publish_stream",
        response_type = "token",
        display = "touch",
        redirect_uri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"
    });
Browser.Navigate(authUrl);
```

My Browser Navigated event only fires once with the following URL:
https://m.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=281638808668585&signed_next=1&next=https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.facebook.com%252Fconnect%252Flogin_success.html&scope=publish_stream&response_type=token&client_id=281638808668585&ret=login&cancel_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?error=access_denied&error_code=200&error_description=Permissions+error&error_reason=user_denied%23_=_&display=touch&_rdr

I can remember the app showing me the login window once, after which I had to allow access, but it has not done so again.

I believe the Browser need to keep redirecting till `facebookClient.TryParseOAuthCallbackUrl(e.Uri, out oauthResult)`is successfull, after which I can continue to post the picture but it never gets there, any ideas? I don't get any exceptions